# Difference between document.body.contentEditable='true'; and document.designMode='on';

Tags: javascript

It seems both allow you to edit the document, so what's the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case, they're equivalent.  `contentEditable` makes the element it's applied to and all descendant nodes editable.  `designMode` makes the entire document editable.

There's a great summary of the history of both properties available on the WHATWG blog —
[The Road to HTML 5: contentEditable](http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-contenteditable).  It's worth a read, if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

contentEditable allows to make specific elements editable while designMode affects the whole document.

Comment: I would say yes, there are some minor differences, see: http://nagoon97.wordpress.com/2008/04/20/differences-between-designmode-and-contenteditable/ . I would prefer designMode, it's more compatible.